# WPF DataGridColumn Not Accepting 0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, datagrid

I have a `DataGridTextColumn` that I want to display a phone number in. I allow the user to type into the Column, and naturally they will need to type in a number beginning with 0.

However, whenever the user types in 0 the Column removes it so it is simply a telephone number without the 0. For example;

[image]

All these telephone numbers have 0's in but as you can see they have been removed by the `DataGrid`. How can I keep the 0's in my `DataGridColumn`?

EDIT: `xaml`

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="companyDataGrid" FontSize="14" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column"
EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowEditEnding="OnSubcontractorDataGridRowEditEnding" SelectionChanged="OnSubcontractorGridSelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Package" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Package, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telephone" Width="*" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: can you show your XAML? or are you doing this in code behind?

Comment: @MikeT Hi Mike, I've added in my `XAML`

Comment: and just to confirm PhoneNumber is a string field?

Comment: @MikeT It wasn't , no. After following StepUp's recommendation its working fine, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to store telephone numbers into `string` type, not `integer` in order to save leading zero.

C# automatically deletes leading zero in `int` values. You can test it:

```
string value = "01";
int i = int.Parse(value);
//Debugger says i=1 cause it is integer
```

If you store numbers in string, then it results:

```
string str = string.Format("{0:(000) 000-0000 x 000}",      
                        double.Parse("0234567890123"));
```

Will result in "(023) 456-7890 x 123"

So if you want to keep leading zero in the telephone number, you should store it in `string` variable.